# Attempt to assign property of non-object Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel

Can someone tell me why I'm getting this error ? Everything works fine until this starts: `$ticket->used += 1;` I clearly find a ticket and store it in `$ticket` variable, but why I can't manipulate it and assign value ?

```
   public function getTicket(TicketUserRequest $request)
   {

    $ticket = Ticket::where('code', '=', Input::get('code'))->count() > 0;
    if ($ticket) {

        $input['user_id'] = $request->user()->id;
        $input['code'] = $request->input('code');
        Auth::user()->balance += 50;
        Auth::user()->save();

        $ticket->used += 1;
        $ticket->save();

        TicketUser::create( $input );

        return redirect()->back();   

    }  

   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $ticket = Ticket::where('code', '=', Input::get('code'))->count() > 0;
```

`$ticket` here will be a boolean, and *not* an object.  It is similar in substance to this:

```
$count = 12;
$iAmABooleanVariable = $count > 0;
```

This will get you a *collection* object:

```
$ticket = Ticket::where('code', '=', Input::get('code'))->get();
```

Which you can then use in a test to see if the count is 0:

```
if($ticket->count() > 0) {
    // Do something
}
```

If there's only supposed to be *one* ticket with a specific code, you can do this and get a *model* object that you can manipulate directly as you're trying to do:

```
$ticket = Ticket::where('code', '=', Input::get('code'))->first();
```

Comment: Now I'm getting this `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$used`

Comment: Np. FYI I believe `first()` will return `null` if no records matching the query were found, so you shouldn't have to change your `if` test